# Make windows in Windows 10 resizeable by drag when window are maximized

Tags: windows-10, window, resizing

I wonder why it is not possible to resize windows when they are maximized. Is there any way to make it possible?

Thanks.

https://prnt.sc/mgtm5f

Comment: Short answer, No.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see this being possible.

A maximized windows has some special characteristics and is not just one that has been resized to the maximum dimensions of the screen. A maximized window has a position and size larger than the screen thus placing the borders outside the visible area. Since the mouse cannot go beyond the screen dimensions the borders cannot be reached and used to resize the window. This is all documented behavior and has been the case since the early days of Windows. Any change in this would likely have compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution ready-to-go, but since the other answer is theoretical anyway, I would like to argue that where there's a will, there's a way.

LMiller7 raises good points. To avoid compatibility issues, I suggest maybe you would stop using the native maximize button, and build your own. E.g. draw an interactable overlay button on top of the native one so that the native feature is never used.

That "custom maximize button" should resize the selected window to take up ALMOST all of the screen so that the drag handles are still onscreen and usable. I believe this should absolutely be possible, since I have used apps that can resize windows to specific dimensions. (e.g. PowerToys FancyZones)

---

1. Albeit, with the tradeoff that you would have a border on the edge
   of your window/screen.
2. The other tradeoff of neglecting the native maximize feature:
   you'd lose out on saving a window size, by toggling between

   - maximize (the box icon button), and
   - restore (the double box icon, appears when window is maximized, same position as maximize button)
3. There'd also be added performance overhead.
4. Functionality and UX may be difficult/impossible to achieve well with an overlay approach.

---

[1.] is a negative to me because I care a lot for aesthetics. In Mac, window borders look "clean" and unobtrusive, unlike Windows' (10 or 11) less appealing borders. I would want to try to change the border style somehow, but it's a small thing. You could probably get used to it, or worst case look into modifications to border style, see if that's feasible somehow.

[2.] could be worked around by implementing your own system to switch between the maximized and restored dimensions.

[3.] should be negligible if optimized well, and is a necessary cost for a great UX.

[4.] is the drawback where I am quite uninformed. I suspect my idea could be clunky due to technical limitations (the overlay must be aligned correctly, may be slow to update) but still at least "possible".

---

TL;DR In conclusion, there is "a way to make it possible", though this may be unfeasible if you aren't a skilled programmer with free time.

To address another detail of the question, "I wonder why it isn't possible": AFAIK there is no real reason aside from simplicity and consistency. You can do this on Mac OS and it's a godsend for window management!